# Im trying to put title but Its totally

Tags: php

```
$news = htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents("https://www.ethnews.com/rss.xml"), ENT_QUOTES);

echo $news->channel->item[0]->title;
```

Comment: Sorry for Title....

Comment: Im trying to echo this rss feed

Comment: but it's totally what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use [simplexml_load_file()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php), i.e.:

```
$url = "https://www.ethnews.com/rss.xml";
$feed = simplexml_load_file($url);

foreach($feed->channel->item as $story) {
    echo $story->title;
    # other options :
    # echo $story->desc;
    # echo $story->link;
    # echo $story->date;
}
```

---

If you just need the first title, you can use:

```
$url = "https://www.ethnews.com/rss.xml";
$feed = simplexml_load_file($url);
echo $feed->channel->item[0]->title;
```